# How to download azure repo compare files as a result?

Tags: azure, repo

Azure Repo has a compare feature that can be used to compare changes across different fork Question: how can I download the result of such a compare as a file?
please suggest a way to download the compare file from azure repo

Answer (score 0):

Azure devOps repo support hit commands. Download the tool on your local machine and follow instructions here https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-compare-local-and-remote-branches.html to compare two files. You can use ‘>>output.txt towards the end of commandline to output the console data to text file.

Comment: you mean the git tool or is there is any other tool

Comment: yes sorry typo in my comment above. Please use the git tool and use that to compare local and remote files.